# Blurry images in Plone Kupu

Tags: image, plone, plone-3.x

I use the Kupu editor in Plone3 to insert images in the website, automatic scaling images, and make a smaller thumb with a link to the original image.

This is a tutorial  of how we do that:
http://www.contentmanagementsoftware.info/plone-book/kupu/insert-image-properties/index_html

Kupu creates a new scaled image (not only scaling with css, but scaling it for real), and the result is that images become a little blurry. I don't know if this issue is related to [this document](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/resizing-images-in-kupu).

**The question comes to my mind.** Is there anybody who find this issue too? Is there any way to fix it?

I think the only way to achieve a great quality images is scaling them manually with photoshop or some graphic editor. But seems that Kupu doesn't allow to do that. You must swallow with its manners and upload its self-generated images.

Comment: Plone handles the scaling; all Kupu has to do is show you what size options you have. The second document you linked to allows you to fine-tune the sizing by allowing you to set *browser*-side width and height properties. Can you give us an example of an image that became blurry? What was the original image size, at what size are you displaying it?

Comment: Browser-size, I think means "not-real scaling, but css scaling". Sorry, my skills of english language are a bit poor... I would confirm the issue related in that document has nothing to do with the mine one. Thanks.

Comment: The second document talks about CSS scaling; the first shows you Plone's automatic scaling options (Large, Preview, Mini, Thumb, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a bit too localized, but we find main error. I want to respond in case that any user will be in the same situation...

Kupu scale images to a certain width and height. And later, the css rescaled again a little bigger, making blurry images.

That is the main problem, we reduced an image, then enlarged it browser-side again. We didn't notice until now that there was css behind the kupu implementation and "overriding" (so to speak) our configuration.

Comment: Glad you found a solution! Yes, CSS scaling images back *up* would result in blurry images. Choose a larger image to scale down instead, perhaps. :-)